# 16 bit registers with high/low byte implementation

Tags: c#

Searching failed me, so i just asking it directly
Is there any way in C# to make 16bit WORD with separated access?
Something like AX and another common registers
On c++ it's like

```
union unsigned short
{
    struct
    {
        char low,high;
    } parts;
    u16 whole;
} a;
#define ax a.whole
#define al a.parts.low
#define ah a.parts.high
```

and than i would use it just like

> ax=0x3d5f;
>   ah=0x04;

and such. So the question is - Is there any way to do this without class\structures fro which one i hade to use it like

> AX.h=0x04

or like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use the [StructLayout] attribute, specifying LayoutKind.Explicit so you can directly control the placement of a field.  Then for each field, use [FieldOffset] to control its offset from the start of the structure.  Like:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct X86Register {
   [FieldOffset(0)] public byte   reg8;    // Like AL
   [FieldOffset(1)] public byte   reg8h;   // Like AH
   [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort reg16;   // Like AX
   [FieldOffset(0)] public uint   reg32;   // Like EAX
   [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong  reg64;   // Like RAX
}
```

Comment: You can use `[FieldOffset(1)]` to get AH in there as well :)

Comment: It is just a structure, like any other structure in C#.  Assign reg16 and read back reg8 and reg8h for example.

Comment: I mean, "how to use this structure" to get some variable's part? Would it be something like `X86Register AX = new X86Register`, and than i just have to use it it like (actually dunno) `AX = 0x053f` for automatic memory allocation, or i have to do it myself, like `AX.reg16=0x053f`? And if it's wrong - would you please show me, how to

Comment: @user2380317 You treat it just like any other `struct` (which is pretty much the same as treating a `class`). For example `var register = new X86Register(); register.reg16 = 0x053f; Console.WriteLine(register.reg8);`.

Answer (score 0):

C# is an object oriented language. There is no way to do ANYTHING without classes or structures in it.

Using a class, it would for instance be implemented like this:

```
public class A
{
    private byte[] raw;

    public A()
    {
        raw = new byte[2];
    }

    public byte Low
    {
        get
        {
            return raw[0];
        }
        set
        {
            raw[0] = value;
        }
    }

    public byte High
    {
        get
        {
            return raw[1];
        }
        set
        {
            raw[1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `char` to represent a 16-bit number. That's what `short` (or `ushort`) is for. `char` is for UTF-16 characters, nothing else.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. And in fact, I am not doing that. The original code requested `char` instead of `byte`. So I assumed that the OP wanted characters, which were `char` in C++.

Comment: I think that's just because `char` is the usual way to write “8-bit integer” in C (even if that's not completely right). I don't see any indication that the question is about actual characters.

Comment: `byte` in C is an 8-bit integer, too. The only difference is signed vs. unsigned. If someone asks for a character in his example code, I assume that this is what he intended to do.

Comment: I looked at [the spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (§6.2.5 and §7.18) and I didn't find `byte` there. There is `int8_t` and `uint8_t`, but that's relatively new and I believe people don't use it much.

Comment: Apparently, I only worked with libraries whenever I used C/C++. Every single library out there defines a byte type. Anyway, you are right, both languages do not know a `byte` keyword. Allow me to edit my answer.